# Unable to mock Cache service worker API for React/Jest unit test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, service-worker, browser-cache

I'm attempting to test a component that has the following code (shortened) which uses the Service Worker API 'Cache' (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache), while the code is working great, I'm having trouble testing it.

React code:

```
useEffect(() => { 
   caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES.backendPlayerInfo).then(async (cache) => {
         const url = 'mysite.com/api/myapi';
         const response = await cache.match(url);
         if(response) {
              //use cached response
         } else {
             //call api
         }
...
```

In my Jest unit test, I'm getting an error when rendering the component that 'cached' is undefined. I may be barking up the wrong tree, but I decided to attempt to mock it like so:

```
global.caches = {
      open: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
        match: jest.fn(),
        put: jest.fn(),
      }),
};
```

But then I just get an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`

What is the proper way to mock/handle the service worker cache API? Could anyone give me an example, I'm having trouble finding anything.

Answer (score 0):

ran into this myself. This is my test that was failing with much the same error as yours, throwing an undefined when setting up the spy there.

```
    // arrange
    const spy = jest.spyOn(self.caches, 'open');

    // act
    const cb = await fetchDidSucceed({
      request: request,
      response: response,
    });

    // assert
    expect(cb).toBe(response);
```

This would result in the same issue you described. I fixed it by setting up a mock on `self` which is what the service worker (Google's workbox) in my case was using.

```
    beforeEach(() => {
     self.caches = {
      open: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
        keys: jest.fn(),
        add: jest.fn()
      });
     }
    });
```